# Grouping results from a group in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have this aggregate function:

```
[{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            rl: "$rl",
            status: "$screener_status"
        },
        total: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        rl: "$_id.rl",
        status: "$_id.status",
        total: "$total"
    }
}
])
```

Which will return this dataset:

```
{ "rl" : "200", "status" : "terminate", "total" : 1 }
{ "rl" : "200", "status" : "in_progress", "total" : 1 }
{ "rl" : "200", "status" : "security_terminate", "total" : 1 }
```

I would like to turn that into one object kind of like this:

```
{
    "rl": "200",
    "status": {
        "terminate": 1,
        "in_progress": 1,
        "security_terminate": 1
    }
}
```

Or at least something simlar to this. I've tried to use different groups on the end but nothing I've tried as worked

Comment: Add this after your group `{
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id.rl",
        statusinfo: {
            $push: {status:"$_id.status", total:"$total"}
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Wow that worked and it was so fast I've spent like an hour on this... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/):

```
[
    {$group: {
        _id: {rl: '$rl', status: '$screener_status'},
        total: {$sum: 1}
    }},
    {$group: {
        _id: '$_id.rl',
        pairs: {$push: {k: '$_id.status', v: '$total'}}
    }},
    {$project: {
        _id: 0,
        rl: '$_id',
        status: {$arrayToObject: '$pairs'}
    }}
]
```

Which gets you the exact result:

```
{
    "rl" : "200",
    "status" : {
        "security_terminate" : 1.0,
        "in_progress" : 1.0,
        "terminate" : 1.0
    }
}
```